# rspec - how to check that allow_blank exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord, rspec

I have a test for uniqueness which works:

```
it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:name).case_insensitive }
```

however when I try to do a similar test for name it fails

```
it { should validate_presence_of(:name).allow_blank }
```

I get this error: `undefined method`allow_blank'`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [this list](https://web.archive.org/web/20150904101414/http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rspec_shoulda), there's no method in shoulda that can be chained to validate_presence_of that would support what you want to do.
Have a look at [the source code of the matcher here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/validate_presence_of_matcher.rb).

However, there is another matcher you can use:

```
it { should allow_value("", nil).for(:name) }
```

Which tests if blank values can be applied to your attribute.

The full test would then be

```
it { should validate_presence_of(:name) }    
it { should allow_value("", nil).for(:name) }
```

Comment: There is no allow_blank matcher: undefined method `allow_blank' for #<Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveModel::ValidatePresenceOfMatcher..>

Comment: @PETERBROWN I see I copied the `.allow_blank` method from the question. Edited that out, so now it should be all correct.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore, as `validate_presence_of` expects a blank space to fail. :/

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no matcher for `allow_blank` so you could use `allow_value(@subject.name.blank?)` or something similar.

As a side note, I never test model validation using the validation methods themselves as you're actually testing the wrong thing. I test them using creation of the model in question, passing it valid or invalid parameters. This will test the model much more accurately and in real-world conditions.