# undefined method `allow_blank' - ShouldaMatchers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, shoulda

I have simple model that looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :administration
  validates :administration, presence: true, allow_blank: true
end
```

and spec that looks like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User, type: :model do
  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:administration).allow_blank }
end
```

running this spec returns me:

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `allow_blank' for #<Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveModel::ValidatePresenceOfMatcher:0x0000000b7f27a8>
```

Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [rspec - how to check that allow\_blank exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413906/rspec-how-to-check-that-allow-blank-exists)

Comment: I saw that topic. Didn't find solution for my problem there.

Comment: What specifically didn't it answer for you?

Comment: did you get things working here?

Comment: I rewrite this spec to not use shoulda.

Answer (score 0):

`it { should allow_value("", nil).for(:administration) }`

should work.

Comment: you copied it from old answer. Since then there is a new recommended `expect` syntax.

Comment: You can write, ```subject { user }```    ```expect(subject).to allow_value("", nil).for(:administration)```. But I have some confusion with this ```subject ``` syntax. So I always avoid it. :)